# how i can add database to the package of netbean project

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, netbeans, jdbc

I want to create a program to use it on any computer , so when i install it must import the database.sql from its place .. so i have to add it to the package of project , but when i did i have a message that's tells (java.sql.SQLException : no such table : table-name) , even though am sure that I have a table there. 
so could u tell me where is the problem . or if there is any way to import the database from project folder wherever it was ? 
thank you !

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class dbc {
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet rs = null ;
        PreparedStatement pst = null ;

        public static Connection ConnecrDb() {        
          try {            
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Tab.sqlite");          
            return conn;          
          }catch (Exception e ){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e)
          return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and there is a file in the package called Tab.sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: You should copy/create a database and collect the database location path then when you are try to get a connection, should put the database urlPath into `DriverManager.getConnection(urlPath);`

Also you can try:

```
public Connection DBConn() {
    String connStr = "jdbc:sqlite:<location path>/myDB.db";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(2);
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem , I should write this :

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/src/Tab.sqlite");
```

if I want to import the sql database from package of project I have to add `/src/myDB.sqlite` 
thank you all :D